# Dynamics CRM 2013 and SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, dynamics-crm

Does SharePoint Foundation 2013 support Dynamics CRM 2013 for document management?

Or is it supported only on SharePoint 2013 Server?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 versions aren’t supported for use with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 document management.

SharePoint integration is supported for SharePoint Server 2010, SharePoint Server 2013, and SharePoint Server Online.

Go thorugh this MSDN article, will give more update detail.

- [SharePoint Document Management software requirements for Microsoft
  Dynamics CRM 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699758.aspx)
- [Integrate SharePoint with Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334768.aspx)

Comment: but in below link under important it says "Currently, Server-based SharePoint integration is not supported with Microsoft Dynamics CRM, does that mean sharepoint server on-premises not supported  (on-premises)."http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699758.aspx#BKMK_enable_servertoserver

Comment: totally contradictory information, on the same link first they said supported then said not supported...their are two authentication method, i believe one is supported and other is not...List component support is supported but Server-based SharePoint integration support is not supported yet....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699758.aspx#BKMK_enable_servertoserver